# Solubility of Aluminium Halides by Fajans rule

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility

According to **Fajan's rule** polarizability of anion is directly related to the size and hence  the covalent character would be more.

Now going by this definition aluminium chloride having greater covalent character would be less soluble than aluminium fluoride, but in reality it's just the opposite. How do I account for this?

Comment: Also why isnt fajans rule applicable here and where else does it not hold true ?

Comment: You should consider *all* parameters before trying to conclude something. Have you considered the fact that fluoride is a small anion, and that increases lattice energy?

Comment: Fajans rule for solubility is applicable only in polar solvent . In nonpolar solvent it is reverse the order in polar So check the solvent